# Changing NDSolve to DSolve in a existing code

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have the following code:

```
vi[t_] = 230*Sqrt[2]*Sin[2*Pi*50*t];
vr[t_] = Abs[vi[t]] // 
  PiecewiseExpand[#, t \[Element] Reals] &; system = {vo'[t] == 
   charging[t] vr'[t] - (1 - charging[t]) vo[t]/(r c), vo[0] == 0};
control = {charging[0] == 1, WhenEvent[vr'[t] < 0, charging[t] -> 0], 
  WhenEvent[And[vo[t] < vr[t], charging[t] == 0, vr'[t] > 0], 
   charging[t] -> 1]}; pars = {r -> 1/(10), c -> 1};
sol = NDSolve[{system, control} /. pars, vo, {t, 0, 1}, 
   DiscreteVariables -> charging \[Element] {0, 1}];
```

Now, I want an exact solution (because I want to integrate the final values from $0$ to $\infty$). So I need to use `DSolve` instead of `NDSolve`.

> Question: How can I use `DSolve` in my code?

Comment: Do you have know for a fact that an exact solution actually exists for your equation though?

Answer (score 1):

Well, to use `DSolve` in place of `NDSolve`, you have to make sure that an exact solution actually exist for you function. Notice that you can still use integrate to a large enough number in place of infinity if the solve is converging. If not , then the answer probably doesn't exist.